# Angularjs: dynamically populated option select returns object instead of value

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I am trying to dynamically populate the `options` of a `<select>` HTML element in AngularJS with values gotten from the database. According to the documentation, I tried this:

```
<select 
    name="student_id" 
    ng-model="studentData.student_id"
    ng-options="student as student.name for student in students track by student.id"  
    class="form-control"> 
    <option value="">-- choose Agency --</option>
</select>
```

This worked fine. It populated the `option` `select` HTML element and I could see the dropdown values filled with the names of the students and the corresponding value of `option` element was the `student_id`.

The problem now is that when I fill out all the form and attempt to submit, it submits a **student object** instead of the **student_id** as the value of the `option select` element.

---

How do I submit `student_id` instead of the **student object**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you select your whole `student` object. Change this line

```
ng-options="student as student.name for student in students track by student.id"
```

To:

```
ng-options="student.id as student.name for student in students track by student.id"
```

---

*Note: I think you should also remove the `track by`, I guess it does not bring anything here.*